# Data returned in phmyadmin but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, when I run this SQL query in phpmyadmin data are returned, but if I run it in php code it's not working, this is the first time I noticed something like that can be possible.[image of data in phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Kjl.png).

Thank you for your time guys.

**PHP CODE**

```
else if(!isset($_GET["username"])){
      #echo $returned_userid;
      try{
        $prepare = $readDB->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM follows WHERE follower_id = :followerid");
        $prepare->execute([
          ":followerid" => $returned_userid
        ]);

        $followingArray = [];

        while($row = $prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          $followingArray[] = $row["user_id"];
        }

        // helper function
        function beautify($user){
          return "'" . $user . "'";
        }

        $mod = array_map("beautify", $followingArray);

        $users = implode($mod, ",");

        echo $users;

        $prepare = $readDB->prepare("SELECT P.post_id as post_id, P.user_id as user_id, P.post_published as post_published, P.post_content as post_content, COUNT(L.post_id) as post_likes, U.user_username FROM posts P LEFT OUTER JOIN likes L ON P.post_id = L.post_id LEFT OUTER JOIN users U ON U.user_id = P.user_id WHERE P.user_id IN ('16', '5') GROUP BY P.post_id");

        // $prepare->execute([
        //   ":usersarray" => $users
        // ]);

        $rowCount = $prepare->rowCount();

        echo $rowCount;

        $postsArray = [];

        while($row = $prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          $post = new Post($row["post_id"], $row["user_id"], $row["user_username"], $row["post_published"], $row["post_content"], $row["post_likes"]);
          $postsArray[] = $post->returnPostObject();
        }

        $returnData["rows_returned"] = $rowCount;
        $returnData["posts"] = $postsArray;

        $res = new Response();
        $res->setSuccess(true);
        $res->setHttpStatusCode(200);
        $res->setData($returnData);
        $res->send();
        exit;

      }catch(PDOException $e){
            $response = new Response();
            $response->setHttpStatusCode(500);
            $response->setSuccess(false);
            $response->addMessage($e->getMessage());
            $response->send();
            exit;
        }
```

**SQL query**

```
SELECT P.post_id as post_id, P.user_id as user_id, P.post_published as post_published, P.post_content as post_content, COUNT(L.post_id) as post_likes, U.user_username FROM posts P LEFT OUTER JOIN likes L ON P.post_id = L.post_id LEFT OUTER JOIN users U ON U.user_id = P.user_id WHERE P.user_id IN ('16', '5') GROUP BY P.post_id
```

Comment: you have $prepare->execuet(..)  commented .. this way the query is not executed

Comment: *"but if I run it in php code it's not working"* You sound like a manager now..  Are you running PHP in debug mode so you always see errors, notices and warnings ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland do you mean php_flag  display_errors  on?

Comment: More or less and error_reporting(E_ALL)

Comment: I mean error_reporting(E_ALL) is same as php_fag display_errors on isn't it?